# Python: Is there a way to schedule Celery tasks to run only within a specific time frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, celerybeat

I have an app that uses Celery and I would like it to only allow the workers to run the tasks between certain times of the day.

For example:

- I'd want my tasks to only be executed between 2:00 and 4:00 everyday
- If all tasks aren't completed from the queue in that time frame, then they are carried over to the next day to be run between 2:00 and 4:00
- I can add more tasks to the queue at any time

I've been looking at [Celery's Periodic Tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) but this only seems to be able to set the time in which tasks are exectuted without setting a time at which they should cease:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 A.M
    'add-every-monday-morning': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

There might not be a way to do this with Celery out of the box but I just wanted to check before I started to build something that could automate this.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: How have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do with what's available natively in celery is set the `expires` option on your task to 2 hours.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 A.M
    'add-every-monday-morning': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=14),
        'expires': 60 * 60 * 2,  # 2 hours
    ...
```

The rest of the functionality you will need to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically [add](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues-adding-consumers) and [cancel consumers for queues](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#std:control-cancel_consumer). Just set up a cronjob that adds the consumers at 2am, remove them at 4am. You could also use a scheduled celery task, but then you have to set up a second queue to ensure it gets executed.

Just make sure that your queue is able to hold all tasks that are enqueued in the meantime.